# Matching discriminants real quadratic and cubic fields

Tags: number-theory, class-field-theory

This goes back to my first MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12486/integers-not-represented-by-2-x2-x-y-3-y2-z3-z  and before that to Irving Kaplansky.

I put a fair amount of related information at [http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/inhom.cgi](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/%7Ejagy/inhom.cgi)

My original construction was inhomogeneous polynomials of the same sort as $2 x^2 + xy + 3 y^2 + z^3 - z.$  The   result  is that  $2 x^2 + xy + 3 y^2 + z^3 - z \neq \pm C,$  where $C =  1, 599, 14951, 9314449, $  and in general Pell type  $27C^2 - 23 F^2 = 4$  for some integer $F.$

Over the weekend I shared this with a conference   and gave a vague mention of the case when the binary quadratic form is indefinite. The example I mentioned (disc 229) was $3 x^2 + 13 xy - 5 y^2    + z^3 - 4z  .$   By my computer search, it appears  that $3 x^2 + 13 xy - 5 y^2    + z^3 - 4z \neq \pm 1 .$

The very next example is discriminant 257. In Henri Cohen's *A Course in Computational Number Theory*   the cubic, table B.4, page 522, is given as $x^3 - 5 x - 3.$   I like this version, the computer gets $2 x^2 + 15 xy - 4 y^2    + z^3 - 5z \neq \pm 3 .$  This includes facts such as :   $2 x^2 + 15 xy - 4 y^2$  represents a number $n$ if and only if it represents $-n.$

I was looking for larger discriminants  at [TABLE](https://hobbes.la.asu.edu/NFDB/)   and found $x^3 - x^2 - 4x +3$  instead.  It does have discriminant $257,$   same Galois group. John Voight gives the same. However,  I now find $2 x^2 + 15 xy - 4 y^2    + z^3 - z^2 - 4z \neq - 3 .$   It gives the value $3$   when, for example, $x=3, y=-3, z=6$  or $x=5, y=-1, z=4$

Oh, the pattern suggests a finite count of missing numbers when the binary is indefinite. I'll need to find that again.  Found it, for Cohen's version, $\Delta(x^3 - 5x - c) = 500 - 27 c^2$  and $\Delta = 257 $ means $c = \pm 3$

So, there is the question, why are the given cubics different,  $x^3  -5x -3$  and $x^3 - x^2 - 4x +3;$   also why the seeming difference in the missing integers, two for the first version, single missing number in the second?

From comments by Aphelli  confirming they are the same cubic field,
$$     \left( 3 - x^2  \right)^3 - 5    \left( 3 - x^2  \right) - 3 = -  \left( x^3 - x^2 - 4x + 3  \right)   \left( x^3 + x^2 - 4x - 3  \right)     $$

$$  \left(  x^2 - x - 3  \right)^3  -   \left(  x^2 - x - 3  \right)^2 -4  \left(  x^2 - x - 3  \right)  +3 =   \left(   x^3 - 5x - 3 \right)   \left( x^3 - 3x^2 - 2x + 7  \right)   $$
In particular, when the  factor of interest on the right hand side is zero, the left hand side is also zero.

Comment: I’m sorry, I really don’t understand what you’re talking about… what exactly are these discriminants? What’s the link between the quadratic part, the cubic part, and the constant?

Comment: @Aphelli  for Cohen's version, the discriminant of the cubic $z^3 - 5z + c$   is  $500 - 27 c^2.$  When $c = \pm 3$  this is $257. $  The discriminant of the binary quadratic $2x^2 + 15xy-4 y^2$   is $257.$   Let's see, the relationship between quadratic and cubic begins with the table on the fourth page of Hudson and Williams  http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf

Comment: For the question about the cubics, because of LMFDB data about cubic fields they should indeed represent the same number field: my guess would be that if $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3-x^2-4x+3$, one should be able to find a second-degree polynomial $q(\alpha)$ which is a root of $x^3-5x-3$. Can you run a computer search (or did you try already)?

Comment: @Aphelli  thanks,  haven't checked that yet. I think   the best explanation  about combining the quadratics and cubics is in   http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/jagy_conjecture_23.pdf   Most of that is irrelevant for the case $C = \pm 1$ Then a much better treatment is Kevin Buzzard at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12486/integers-not-represented-by-2-x2-x-y-3-y2-z3-z   He gave the problem to a Master's student. I asked him for the student's writeup, maybe I can find it off my old computer.

Comment: (Corrected): I just checked, if $u$ is a root of $x^3-x^2-4x+3$ then $3-u^2$ is a root of $x^3-5x-3$.

Comment: Conversely, if $v$ is a root of $x^3-5x-3$, then $v^2-v-3$ should be a root of $x^3-x^2-4x+3$ (don’t hesitate to double-check though). I’m  surprised, I expected a certain asymmetry to account for the “missing integers” you were talking about… that’s certainly puzzling.

Comment: @Aphelli  thank you.  I tried your idea last night, I couldn't get anywhere  with it. I'll   see what I can manage in checking your quadratics.

Comment: @Aphelli   checked 3-u^2   numerically, beautiful.  The thing I missed last night    was permuting the  roots  (cyclic) of the second cubic...  I have a book called Cubic Fields by Hambledon and someone, maybe there is something quick.

Comment: @WillJagy: An upvote from me, for a certainly interesting question from you!  If I may just ask, is this topic tangentially related to [odd perfect numbers](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/articles/opn-mass-rev-060211.pdf), seeing that you mentioned [John Voight](https://www.mathgenealogy.org/id.php?id=99302)? If your answer is *NO*, can you recommend a gentle introduction to *Quadratic Forms* instead?  Thank you, Professor Jagy!  =)